# Trying to hide gif after a specific image loads

Tags: javascript, html

Below is 3 different files.  The firstfile is the HTML file im working on currently.
the secondfile is the javascript

ive been trying to hide the gif when the trigger image loads but it doesnt seem to want to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Machine Learning For Bathymetry</title>
    <link href="../../static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../static/script.js" defer>  </script>
    

    
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class = "container">

      <div class = "button-div">
      <button type="button" id="modelTrain">Train Model</button>
      <button type="button" id="dataclean">Data Cleaning</button>
      <button type="button" id="testData">Test Model</button>
      <button type="button" id="outputProfile">Create Bathymetry</button>
      </div>

      <div class = "div-1">
        <h1> Picture Perfect Ocean Floor Mapping: </h1>
        <h1>A Machine Learning Bathymetry Study</h1>
        
        <p>Welcome to our machine learning project!</p>
        <form method="POST", onsubmit="disableButton()">
          <button name="PythonGo", id="cleanButton"> <p>Clean Data!</p></button>
        </form>
      

        <div id="my-gif">
          <img src="https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp" alt="My GIF">
        </div>
        
      

        {% if parseComplete %}
          <br>
          
          <img id="trigger-image" img src="../../static/my_plot.png" class = plotPicture alt="Trigger Image" onload="hideGif()">
        {% endif %}

      </div>
    </div>
   

  </body>
  
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    function createParagraph() {
      const para = document.getElementById('functionality');
      para.textContent = 'No Functionality Yet! Nice try though!';
  
    }


  
    function openDataWindow() { 
      window.location.href = '../BathymetryML'
    }
  
    function openFileWindow() { 
      window.location.href = '../../dragAndDrop'
    }
  
    function openTestWindow() { 
      window.location.href = '../../testPage'
      }
  
    function openOutputWindow() { 
        window.location.href = '../../outputPage'
      }

    function runPython(){
      
      const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
  
      let pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py');
  
      pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
          console.log(message);
      })
  
      pyshell.end(function (err) {
          if (err){
              throw err;
          };
          console.log('finished');
      });
    }

    function hideGif() {
      const gifDiv = document.getElementById('my-gif');
      gifDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }

  
    const buttonOne = document.querySelector('#dataclean');
    buttonOne.addEventListener('click', openDataWindow);

    const buttonTwo = document.querySelector('#modelTrain');
    buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', openFileWindow);
  
    const buttonThree = document.querySelector('#testData');
    buttonThree.addEventListener('click', openTestWindow);
  
    const buttonFour = document.querySelector('#outputProfile');
    buttonFour.addEventListener('click', openOutputWindow);

    const buttonFive = document.querySelector('#runTheTest');
    buttonFive.addEventListener('click', runPython);

    



   
  });
```

Ive tried lots of different combos but i cant seem to get the gif to hide after triggerimage loads

below i have also added how my files are setup in case this may be an issue

i also updated the code above to include one of the answers below but does not work.

[File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30acy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the hideGif function running once the HTML img element loads in the "onload" event listener.

```
<img id="trigger-image" img src="../../static/my_plot.png" class = plotPicture alt="Trigger Image" onload="hideGif()">
```

Once the image loads, you are then waiting for it to load again.

```
  triggerImg.onload = () => {
    gifDiv.style.display = 'none';
  };
```

However, it won't load again because it will have already loaded. That means the code inside that function will never run.

Try refactoring your hideGif function to this:

```
  function hideGif() {
      const gifDiv = document.getElementById('my-gif');
      gifDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Then, move that function outside of the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

Also, remove the `defer` attribute from your `<script>` tag in your HTML. This causes the loading of the script and the parsing of your document to basically run in parallel, which could cause unwanted side effects.

You can then even move that `<script>` tag below the `<body>` tag to ensure that everything in the document is fully parsed before running any Javascript.

The process will then be:

1. trigger-image is loaded at some point in time
2. Once loaded, it will run hideGif()
3. Inside hideGif(), you query the DOM for the GIF
4. Hide the GIF

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This did not work.
i changed my function but still says on the function "'hideGif' is declared but its value is never read"

Comment: Is it possible to move the hideGif() function outside of the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener? I would also try moving that function into its own <script> tag below the <body> in your HTML file if moving it outside of the event listener doesn't work.

Comment: it worked when i moved it outside the body tag below my html file. Do you have any idea why it has to be this way. Shouldnt the html file know about the function in the JS file

Comment: It has to do with the way that you are importing the script. Usually, scripts are loaded in a linear fashion, meaning that if your `<script>` tag is at the top of your document, it will load first before moving on to parse your HTML. However, since it has the `defer` attribute on it, this means it will load parallel, or at the same time, to the parsing of the document. This could cause the HTML to load first. So in this case, the `<img>` will load before the script, call hideGif(), but since the script hasn't finished loading yet, hideGif() will not yet be defined and can't be called.